Exploring the Impact of Transition Metal Doping Percentage on Hydrogen Evolution Reaction Catalysis in Transition Metal Dichalcogenides using DFT
Transition metal dichalcogenides (TMDCs) are extensively researched for their efficiency as catalysts in the hydrogen evolution reaction (HER).
I aim to employ Density Functional Theory (DFT) to investigate the impact of doping transition metals (TMs) into TMDCs on HER.
For instance, my focus lies on scrutinizing the HER catalytic activity of nickel (Ni) doped into molybdenum disulfide (MoS2) across varying percentages (e.g., Ni/Mo ratios of 5%, 10%, 25%, etc.).
What would be the optimal sequence of calculations for conducting this comprehensive study?

"What would be the optimal sequence of calculations for conducting this comprehensive study?" is a little broad for me personally. I can in principle answer a more focused version of this question. For example, catalysis involves surfaces, and surfaces are extremely complicated due to having many variable parts. Therefore, there can in principle be many different studies of the same material and dopant, focusing on distinct aspects of the material, its surfaces, and their interaction with water for catalysis. So what is of the highest interest to the poster?

@Andrey Poletayev: Doping will occur on the exposed surface slab corresponding to the most intense peak in its XRD (e.g., 011). I aim to assess how the HER catalytic activity changes with increasing doping percentage.

From the literature, I learned about evaluating catalytic activity by calculating the Gibbs free energy of H adsorption, as the adsorption of H atoms to the catalytic surface is a critical step in this reaction. Additionally, I'll examine the Projected Density of States, as a higher number of states near the Fermi level suggests increased activity. However, considering potential multiple H adsorption sites in pristine or doped structures, this method may involve numerous calculations. I seek guidance on the optimal calculation sequence for a comprehensive study.
